# How to access li element dynamically using jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to access all list element using jquery selector dynamically.

**case 1: Static id**

```
$('#milk > ul > li').sort(function(a,b){

   });
```

This is how i can access a nested li list.

**case 2:   Dynamic id**

```
      var dId ='milk';
```

Now using this same id i need to access the nested list element.any idea please?

Comment: Your formatting is very hard to read.  You can use string concatenation with variables to build the selector you need.

Comment: i tried that way like
var dId = "'#"+dId+" > ul > li'"

Comment: You don't include the quotes as part of the literal string.  That makes it invalid.

Comment: got it now thank man

Comment: i hope now the formatting is fine

Comment: Definitely better, :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var dId ='milk';
$('#'+ dId +' > ul > li').sort(...)
```

Just use string concatenation to build your selector.